# Hybrid Graphics on Ubuntu 14.04 Problem

Tags: 14.04, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I've got problem to install drivers for AMD graphics card.
When I install a fglrx driver's I've got a black screen and X not start.
Please help and thanks!

My hardware is:

ACER ASPIRE 5820TG

ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 and Intel HD graphics

Answer (score 0):

Hope i will remember correct, but  it could help to change Graphic Bios Settings, 
like enable ATI all the Time and deactivate Intel Graphic  Card.

Comment: It's doesn't work -> When I change parameter in BIOS Ubuntu not response when i reboot computer.